# 'class' relates to 'object' as 'interface' relates to ...?

Tags: class, object, interface, terminology

In development conversations all too often we mix up 'class' and 'object'.  But at least it's possible to differentiate between them.

It's much much worse when it comes to 'interface': I know a class can implement an interface, but e.g. COM it's possible to query an object's 'interface'.

Is there a better term to describe 'the part of that object that implements interface X'?

Comment: It's an interesting question. I suppose that is difficult to find a term that is good - in a natural language, of course - to totally describe this concept.

Comment: @DonCallisto: indeed.   I keep running into ambiguities in discussions about software design.  I guess I'm not the only one.  Sometimes you mean 'API', sometimes you mean 'that aspect of the object'

Answer (score 1):

"Contract".  The interface tells you a contract on which the  thing implementing the interface promises to deliver.

Look up "contract" sometime in a dictionary.  It will tell you that a contract must be specific, with exact deliverables and consequences for failing.